# Браузерное кэширование для изображений, полученных с помощью CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно кэшировать изображение, которое я получил через CURL и создал путь к картинке через .htaccess? Нужно именно браузерный кэш.

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

echo $curl_content;
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^test\.jpg$ test_curl.php [L,QSA]
```

Пробовал разные способы, но ничего не помогло, изображение постоянно грузится заного... Может так нельзя?

Comment: А не пробовали, добавить в заголовки разрешение кэширования  `header('Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000');`?

Comment: @Tunker, пробовал и даже сейчас попробовал, не помогло :(

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста заголовки запроса и полученного ответа от сервера, с самого браузера при получении картинки. Где-то затык идет, возможно нужно добавлять в php обработку запроса `If-Modified-Since`

Comment: @Tunker, тут столько текста не помещается, поэтому залил сюда https://pastebin.com/eTmeqnfh

Comment: https://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/29-all-about-data-url-images/

Comment: Смотрите в ответе сервера: `expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT` - т.е. кэш истек 39 лет назад. Непонятно откуда берется этот заголовок. Попробуйте добавить вручную `header('Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:55:55 GMT')`

Comment: @Tunker, добавил. Теперь браузер в ответе возвращает правильный Expires, но при этом всё равно не берёт картинку из кэша...

Comment: @Tunker, оказалось ещё нужен Pragma: cache. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы картинка кэшировалась, необходимо добавить заголовки в php файл:

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000');
header('Pragma: cache');
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 31536000));
```

Эти заголовки установят срок на который браузеры могу кэшировать картинку 1 год.